# Find out the reason why a BuiltIn function in c# is returning false

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, microsoft.build

How can i find out the reason why a BuiltIn  function in c# is returning false.

For example.

I have implemented Execute method in Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask in one of my child class.This Execute function will return "True" if task i gave to execute success otherwise it returns False.My question is if it returns false how can i find out the reason behind the failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the example given in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.itask%28v=vs.121%29.aspx) from MSDN, where you collect a `Log` of messages that you can later request and analyze to determine what happened.

When the return value is `false`, you retrieve the `Log`, and examine it for failure conditions.  This could be a class constructed any way you like.

Comment: Sorry Don if iam asking is wrong,Iam new to c#

My need is to find out the exact reason why the Task is failing.When i tried to debug it only returns false with out showing the details.How can i ask the compiler to show the details.

Comment: The `Execute` method is yours, right?  Why can't you know?  Keep a log as the example shows, and then ask the log.  There is no way to extract more information from `false`...you have to do it yourself.